# bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot showing: An error occurred while attempting to delete the specified data element. Element not found

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I was dual booting my Dell Inspiron laptop to install ubuntu 20.04 and landed on an intel RST problem. I followed the steps as shown on this site- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347/94

But, in the "bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot" step, I'm getting an error: "An error occurred while attempting to delete the specified data element. Element not found." I tried all three bcdedit codes as shown in the tutorial. How should I proceed?